# How to call returns from other methods is inputs for others?

Tags: java, methods, calendar, return, dayofweek

I'd like to be able to call the return for three methods for the inputs of another. In the example below, I have other methods pulling the month, day, and year from a MM/DD/CCYY date.  Then, the dayOfWeekMethod takes those ints and figures out the day of the week for that given day.  How do I correctly format the first two lines to correctly give me that result? Thanks!!

Here's what I have (which is incorrectly done):

```
System.out.println("The date is "+MyDateTest.dayOfWeekMethod(MyDateTest.monthMethod(date),
 MyDateTest.dayMethod(date), MyDateTest.yearMethod(date));

public static int dayMethod(String dateInput){
    int day = MyDate.getDay(dateInput);

return day;
}

public static int monthMethod(String dateInput){
    int month = MyDate.getMonth(dateInput);

    return month;
}

public static int yearMethod(String dateInput){
    int year = MyDate.getYear(dateInput);

    return year;
 }

public static String dayOfWeekMethod(int month, int day, int year){
    String dayOfWeek = MyDate.dayofWeek(month, day, year);

    return dayOfWeek;
}
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: It seems you just wrote some code out of any method or block (the `System.out.println`), which is why it does not compile. Also, why do you prefix your method calls by the name of the class whereas you **are** in this class ?

Comment: Well you could give a value to your methods. For example int day = dayMethod(date); int month = monthMetod(date); int year = yearMethod(date) and then call dayOfWeekMethod(day,month,year).
For example: System.out.println("The date is "+dayOfWeekMethod(day,moth,year))

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket where you call `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test since i don't have class MyDate but this should work if your class MyDate works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "";
    int day = dayMethod(date);
    int month = monthMethod(date);
    int year = yearMethod(date);
    System.out.println("The date is "+dayOfWeekMethod(month,day,year));
}

public static int dayMethod(String dateInput) {
    int day = MyDate.getDay(dateInput);

    return day;
}

public static int monthMethod(String dateInput) {
    int month = MyDate.getMonth(dateInput);

    return month;
}

public static int yearMethod(String dateInput) {
    int year = MyDate.getYear(dateInput);

    return year;
}

public static String dayOfWeekMethod(int month, int day, int year) {
    String dayOfWeek = MyDate.dayofWeek(month, day, year);

    return dayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance like

```
public static String dayOfWeekMethod(int month, int day, int year){
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
    switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY: return "Monday";
    case Calendar.TUESDAY: return "Tuesday";
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY: return "Wednesday";
    case Calendar.THURSDAY: return "Thursday";
    case Calendar.FRIDAY: return "Friday";
    case Calendar.SATURDAY: return "Saturday";
    case Calendar.SUNDAY: return "Sunday";
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Then you can call it with something like,

```
// System.out.println("The day is "+ dayOfWeekMethod(
//   MyDateTest.monthMethod(date), MyDateTest.dayMethod(date),
//   MyDateTest.yearMethod(date));
System.out.println(dayOfWeekMethod(10, 19, 2014));
```

Output is (the expected)

```
Sunday
```